# What are some intermediate or advanced books on neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request, resource-request, books

Is anyone able to recommend some resources (preferably books) on the topic of neural networks that goes beyond that of introductory reading?

I'm still relatively new to the subject, however, I have successfully created my own neural network, so I wouldn't consider myself a beginner, so I'm looking for something more intermediate.

Comment: For readers and people willing to give an answer: _this question is about **neural networks** (not any other machine learning model or technique) and it is about **intermediate** (or advanced) resources (preferably **books**)_.

Answer (score 4):

[Neural Network Design (2nd edition)](http://hagan.okstate.edu/nnd.html) by Hagan et al. is one resource you could look at. It's a huge tome, weighing in at over 1000 pages in [pdf form](http://hagan.okstate.edu/NNDesign.pdf), but it is freely available (you can also buy a dead-tree version if you really want one).

Answer (score 0):

Another good (although a bit old) and freely available online book (apart from the one suggested in [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/3652/2444)) is [Neural Networks - A Systematic Introduction](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/) (1996) by [Raul Rojas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra%C3%BAl_Rojas). This book contains several exercises at the end of each chapter and covers topics that you will not find in many online courses.